# Ordering by Time part of DateTime

Tags: oracle, datetime

I am trying to write an SQL Query that will only order based on the time field of a `date-time` object in `Oracle DB`. Here is what I tried:

```
 String getPricesQuery = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE SELECTIONID IN (SELECT ID" +
" FROM selection" +
" WHERE EVENTID =" + eventID + ") ORDER BY TIME(TIMEOFISSUE) ASC";
```

I read that the `TIME()` function can be used to extract the time portion of a `Date-Time`, but I imagine it makes it somewhat more complex, when trying to use it in an `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: If you're using Oracle DB then try `ORDER BY to_char(TIMEOFISSUE, 'hh24miss')` . Or maybe it's MySql ?

Comment: A function is just like any other expressions, you can use the function wherever you like, in SELECT clause, in ORDER BY, it makes no difference

Comment: @A.B.Cade Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use :

```
ORDER BY to_char(TIMEOFISSUE, 'hh24miss')
```

Answer (score -1):

ORDER BY TIMEOFISSUE ASC is enough or desc you can use.

Comment: No, that is not what the OP needs. Hee doesn't want to order by time but by hours, minuts and seconds, irrelevant of what date they happen to be in.

Comment: Why wouldn't you delete your answer given that you agree it's wrong?

Comment: It also works. Because its order by date desc means that order by date time also.